# How to delete specific html class with content using Java Html Class

Tags: java, html, regex

Recently I am working on a android project. I am parsing data from wordpress api. But detail post content are in html formet. I have to remove html tags. Using Html.fromHtml().toString() java method I deleted all tags. But there are some image caption which I have to delete. For delete the caption I have to find tag class. So how can I delete this content using Html Class?

```
<p class="wp-caption-text">android m marshmallow</
```

**EDIT :**

Using regular Expression I solved My problem.

Insert Your specific Html in [Regex](https://regex101.com/) and you will get your Regular Expression.

```
 yourHtml = yourHtml.replaceAll("Your_Regular_Expression","");
 yourHtml = Html.fromHtml(yourHtml).toString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a match you can try this:

```
<(\w+).*?class="wp-caption-text".*?>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nE3fF6/2)

I'd like to mention that this is not a perfect solution. Regular expressions are not very good at parsing html since the structures in that markup language are actually too complex to 100% be parseable by regular expressions. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1974671)

Comment: How to use this expression using Html class ? <(\w+).*?class="wp-caption-text".*?>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>

Comment: html.replaceAll("expression", "") ?

Comment: @yeahia2508 google is a wonderful resource. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: I know brother google is wonderful resource. I am searching this problem answer from yesterday. I have to solve this with java not javascript @iismathmizard

Comment: Regular Expression Solved My problem Brother. :)  Thank you. @iismathwizard